# Delete old files in Salesforce - Apex class don't work

Tags: apex, files, contentdocument, delete

Hi I am trying to create an apex class which I could use to regulary delete old files in Salesforce.

```
global class DeleteOldContentDocument implements Schedulable {
 global void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
        List<ContentDocument> ConDoc =[SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument where Id IN ( SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Photo__c = FALSE AND Do_not_delete__c = FALSE AND CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:5)];
        if(!ConDoc.isEmpty())
            delete ConDoc; 
    }
}
```

I think it should work but it doesn't. It doesn't delete the files. The query is fine because it provides 2 IDs but after the apex job is executed, the files remain in system. So the delete doesn't work....

Comment: Does it throw exception? Can you add debug for `List<Database.DeleteResult>`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mariia but I have found the issue. It was not the apex class but it was a file in Asset File  Library which couldn't be deleted and causes that I thought that my class is wrong. I have marked it als DO NOT DELETE so it is now out of my query and the class works fine. I have to exclude the asset files in my query.